# How do I use counter in Python for dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a count of the employees titles

I've tried a lot but I don't think I've applied them correctly to the scenario.

```
employees = [
    {
        "email": "jonathan2532.calderon@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 101,
        "firstname": "Jonathan",
        "lastname": "Calderon",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 3691 5845"
    }]
  




EDIT:

from collections import Counter

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, title,):
        self.title = title

title_count = Counter()

for employee in [Employee("title") for data in employees]:
    title_count[employee.title,] += 1

print(title_count)

Counter({('title',): 4})
```

I can't seem to get the specific names there.

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to run using `employees`?

Comment: first: use `print(title)` to see what you have in variable. Using `print()` can be primitive but useful method to test/debug code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `for title in employees` actually yields a dict object in every iteration since employees is a list of dict objects. While the Counter accepts a dict mapping as input, it isn't quite what you're looking for. The `cnt['title']` simply increases the count by 1 for each iteration, effectively counting the number of dict objects in the employees list.

To count by titles, you have to unpack each of the dict object in your list first.

```
from collections import Counter

titles = [e['title'] for e in employees]
>>>Counter(titles)
Counter({'Mr': 2, 'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is trying to help you out with the error it is giving you.

Try copying and pasting a portion of the error into Google. Then, visit the docs on the [data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) you are trying to use.

It helps to think about the structure of your data:

```
from collections import Counter

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, title, employee_id):
        # all other fields omitted
        self.title = title
        self.employee_id = employee_id
```

Here is some *minimal* data for your problem (arguably you could use a little less).

```
employees = [
    {
        "title": "Mr",
        "employee_id": 1
    },
    {
        "title": "Mr",
        "employee_id": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Mrs",
        "employee_id": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "Ms",
        "employee_id": 4
    }
]
```

Define other necessary data structures.

```
title_count = Counter()

# Just to demo results.
for employee in [Employee(**data) for data in employees]:
    print(f"title: {employee.title} id: {employee.employee_id}")
```

I'll leave the `**data` notation up to Google. But now you have some well-structured data and can process it accordingly.

```
# Now we have some Employee objects with named fields that are
# easier to work with.
for employee in [Employee(**data) for data in employees]:
    title_count[employee.title] += 1

print(title_count) # Counter({'Mr': 2, 'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1})
```